# Angular data not binding to model correctly

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-components

I am currently having an issue with data from my web service call not binding to my angular model correctly (or at least that's what I currently believe the issue to be). This simple example illustrating my issue results in the `<li></li>` elements being rendered on the page however they are all blank and contain empty spans inside of them. There are 3 elements because my DB has 3 entries seeded in it. I have debugged this issue every way I can think of and have been unable to find the cause of this. Below, you can find my simple angular component, the html template for it, my typescript model, and an example of 1 of the 3 json objects returned from my web service:

Angular Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { BabyProfile } from "./baby-profile";
import { BabyProfileService } from "./baby-profile.service";

@Component({
    selector: "baby-profile-list",
    templateUrl: './app/baby-profile/baby-profile-list.component.html'
})

export class BabyProfileListComponent implements OnInit{
    title: string;
    selectedProfile: BabyProfile;
    babyProfiles: BabyProfile[];
    debug: string;

    constructor(private babyProfileService: BabyProfileService,
        private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.babyProfileService.getAll().subscribe(
            babyProfiles => this.babyProfiles = babyProfiles);
    }

    edit(babyProfile: BabyProfile) {
        this.router.navigate(['babyprofile/', babyProfile.Id]);
    }
}
```

html template for the component:

```
<h2>{{title}}</h2>
<div>
   <ul class="list-group">
       <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let babyProfile of babyProfiles"
           (click)="edit(babyProfile)">
           <span>{{babyProfile.FirstName}} {{babyProfile.LastName}}</span>
           <span>{{babyProfile.BirthDate}}</span>
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

typescript model:

```
export class BabyProfile {
    constructor(
        public Id: number = 0,
        public FirstName: string,
        public LastName: string,
        public MiddleName: string,
        public BirthDate: Date,
        public DateCreated: Date,
        public InactiveDate: Date
    ) { }
}
```

and an example of the properties for 1 of the 3 objects my web service is returning (note: this screenshot was taken by replacing `babyProfiles => this.babyProfiles = babyProfiles` with `babyProfiles => console.log(babyProfiles)` and then examining the results in console):
[image]

and an example of the empty `<li><span> </span><span></span></li>` output:
[image]

I noticed the casing was different between my typescript model and the web service response and changed the typescript model and html template to use lower camel case property names however this did not resolve the issue. What am I missing here?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: You can try to debug by changing your binding to `{{babyProfile | json}}`, which will output the JSON of babyProfile. You can then make sure that it matches what you expect. The other thing to check is that your service is returning an object, and not just a string

Comment: just replace `FirstName` and `BirthDate` to  `firstName` and `birthDate` in your template

Comment: user184994 is right. From the structure created by ngFor it looks like you just have some problem with the data structure. Display it as user184994 said and you'll see where the problem lies.

Comment: @user184994 I am fairly new to angular- can you elaborate on exactly where `{{babyProfile | json}}` would go? I have found the answer to my problem already but I'd like to know so I can debug any future problems better. I find it much more difficult to debug client side issues in this environment than in asp.net mvc/razor

Comment: It would go within your span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem lies inside the subscribe, change it as follows

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.babyProfileService.getAll().subscribe((babyProfilesResult) => {
        this.babyProfiles = babyProfilesResult;
    });
}
```

Comment: this did resolve the issue. I'd be curious to know what the difference here actually is. As far as I know, these two statements (mine and yours) should be functionally the same.

Comment: @peggy - Your original syntax would be equivalent to `babyProfiles => { return this.babyProfiles = babyProfiles; }` (see the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)). You can try it to see if it gives you the correct result.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have not added providers in the above @Component decorator below the templateUrl. To call and use any service in the component , we need to add providers. So, try adding the same.

Comment: you can add your service provider to app.module too

Comment: the service is registered in my app.module. I tried your suggestion any way and it did not resolve the issue. thanks for your time though